# Могу я создать exe файл из Python кода в котором записываются текстовые файлы?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Могу я создать exe файл из Python кода в котором записываются текстовые файлы? Создал программу которая собирает из сайта цены на товар и записывает их в файл , при этом сравнивает новые цены со старимы и обновляет весь список. Программа хорошо работает в Pycharm , но при конвертации в exe выдает ошибку что не видит файла с ценами .Конвертировал через pyinstaller. Помогите это устранить пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В папку с exe файлом попробуй кинуть txt файлы, в которые записываются цены

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: помогло код запустился. спасибо